# Java jar creates multiple processes on ubuntu but not on mac

Tags: java, multithreading, process

I've created my first "real" java program and running it for the first time on a production server. What I've noticed is that running the jar (`java -jar foo.jar`) on ubuntu spawns around 13 processes, while running it on my mac only spawns one process (which is expected imo due to the fact that I only spawn one thread in the app).

What could explain this difference?

Comment: Are you sure those are processes (not threads)? There was a bug in old Linux versions that showed Java threads as seperate processes. Maybe something like that?

Comment: @Thilo "Userland threads". If you install `htop` you can configure it to not display them.

Comment: @mbs Indeed, when I turn off displaying of userland threads in htop, those "processes" disappear. Can I conclude that there is nothing to worry about here?

Comment: Yep, just a consequence of the differences between how the OSs report their states.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If you'd like, you could answer the question so I can accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Thilo suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23386060/java-jar-creates-multiple-processes-on-ubuntu-but-not-on-mac#comment35825916_23386060), I believe what you're seeing are not multiple processes but threads. Linux' `top` by default shows individual threads and their usages.

The `htop` tool (`apt-get install htop`) has the ability to hide these "Userland threads" and group the resource usage back into a single entry per process.

```
> htop
> F2 to open options
> Display options
> Hide userland threads (space to toggle)
> F10, Esc or q to return to display
```